# How to view implementation of retrofit's suspend fun

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to understand how retrofit implements the following suspend function:

```
@GET("api/me")
suspend fun getUser(): User
```

Is there anyway that I can access the locally generated implementation code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-2019-06-05),

> Behind the scenes this behaves as if defined as fun user(...):
> Call and then invoked with Call.enqueue. You can also return
> Response for access to the response metadata.

Everything else lies inside the sources like this [class](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/KotlinExtensions.kt). Btw, I'm just curious, why do you need to understand the exact implementation from the Retrofit side?

Comment: > Btw, I'm just curious, why do you need to understand the exact implementation from the Retrofit side?




I am trying to use coroutine to make a GraphQL API call via Shopify's SDK, which means I cannot use retrofit... so I wanted to understand how retrofit is doing it and replicate it :)

Comment: @ChrisB got it! Then yes, it will be the best option to wrap you GrapQL API Calls with the suspendCancellableCoroutine way :)