# Kotlin - Suspend functions in one threaded environments

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, suspend

I'm not entirely sure if my mental model of `suspend` is correct. From what I gathered it seems to mean that a (long running) `suspend` function can be suspended if another function inside it  is marked with `suspend` (which generates a suspension point for the parent function).

To keep it simple lets assume a one threaded environment without asynchronous programming.

```kotlin
launch { //<--- creates a coroutine in which we can use suspend functions
    fetchUserData("Jon") 
}


// and following functions:

suspend fun fetchUserData(userName: String) {
    makeLongRunningNetworkCall(userName) //<---- suspends fetchUserData()
}

suspend fun makeLongRunningNetworkCall(userName: String) {...}
```

My understanding is, that `makeLongRunningNetworkCall()` "takes" `fetchUserData()` "off" the thread so it doesn't block other computations while waiting for the results of `makeLongRunningNetworkCall()`.

But if nothing suspends `makeLongRunningNetworkCall()` isn't the thread still blocked by  `makeLongRunningNetworkCall()`? I mean the "waiting" for the network result has to be done *somewhere* or else the result might be missed?

So for me `suspend` in that case would just make sense if `fetchUserData()` and `makeLongRunningNetworkCall()` would run on different threads, so that `makeLongRunningNetworkCall()` tells its parent function to go home and free its thread until it received a result?!

Is my understanding correct? Or does `suspend` rather mean the whole coroutine is taken off the thread? But then again, who assures the response of the network call is captured?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If something needs waiting, then some thread somewhere needs to do the waiting. In a single thread scenario, coroutines can still be useful if you have lots of background tasks, that mostly hang around inside a `delay()` and do a little bit of work every minute or so.

Comment: Coroutines are just an event loop on steroids. Take a look at `suspendCoroutine` and `suspendCancellableCoroutine `, which basically allow other coroutines to run while waiting for a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct? Or does suspend rather mean the whole coroutine is taken off the thread?

Rather the second, but in order to see the difference, you'll need to add some code in `fetchUserData`. For instance, consider:

```kotlin
suspend fun fetchUserData(userName: String): UserData {
    val userData = makeLongRunningNetworkCall(userName)
    return useData
}
```

If `makeLongRunningNetworkCall` suspends, then `fetchUserData` *does* need to wait for it to resume before executing the rest of its code (the `return`). Similarly, the caller of `fetchUserData` also needs to wait, etc. This is why it's easy to reason about `suspend` functions - they actually run sequentially in that sense.

So, with that in mind, the whole coroutine is suspended (the whole stack up to the initial coroutine builder `launch`), because nothing in the execution stack will carry on until `makeLongRunningNetworkCall` resumes.

> But then again, who assures the response of the network call is captured?

This is a good question. All of the above actually started with the assumption that `makeLongRunningNetworkCall` *does suspend*. This is not an abstract concept. What it means concretely is that the function will return (as in, actually return) a special token called `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED`, so the whole suspension mechanism happens, and the thread starts executing something else.

This means that this function must be cooperative and suspend when it's possible. If the function actually blocks on a network call, then it doesn't actually suspend, and it really does block the thread as you guessed. When functions like this actually suspend, it often means that they offloaded their blocking work to another thread, or that they are truly non-blocking (e.g. callback-based) - but sometimes that just means the offloading happens deeper.

To understand and demystify how this works, I suggest reading this nice article about how `kotlinx.coroutines` is built on just a couple compiler built-ins:
https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-coroutines-animated-part-1-coroutine-hello-world-51797d8b9cd4

Comment: This would be a case for "offloading to another thread", right?https://stackoverflow.com/a/73110711

Comment: Yes, the `enqueue` method of retrofit dispatches the network stuff onto their own thread pool. The coroutines wrapper is just a way to "wait" for the thread pool to finish doing the work, and that "wait" is exactly what suspending coroutines are good at

Answer (score 2):

A suspend function only actually suspends if the suspend functions that it calls also suspend, and so on down the chain.

This is one reason why, by convention, you must never directly call a blocking function in a coroutine or suspend function. All of the suspend functions in the standard library follow this convention. (The other big reason is simplicity. We don't ever have to worry about whether a suspend function might also be a blocking function and tie up a thread that it shouldn't be.)

A common pattern for handling blocking calls is to wrap it in `withContext`. `withContext` is a suspend function that suspends while it runs its code using a CoroutineContext that may be able to handle blocking calls. You can use it with `Dispatchers.Default` or `Dispatchers.IO` as appropriate to make it permissible to call blocking functions within the `withContext` lambda.

If you are using popular libraries such as Retrofit, Jetpack Room, Google Firebase, etc., they expose public `suspend` functions that you can trust do not block, as required by convention. Since **most of these libraries** support both Java and Kotlin, they are actually **using their own thread pools under the hood** rather than Kotlin Coroutines Dispatcher pools. They achieve this by using the low level `suspendCancellableCoroutine` suspend function, which allows finer control of exactly how the coroutine is suspended and resumed.

---

The other aspect of this worth mentioning although you didn't ask about it, is whether the suspend function supports cancellation. Usually, we want to support cancellation if possible. All the standard library suspend functions do. If you are wrapping a long blocking calculation in `withContext`, that's not enough to support cancellation. You must also intersperse some suspending calls or `if (isActive)` checks within your blocking code to give it opportunities to be interrupted and cancelled if you want it to be able to be stopped before finishing.

Comment: So in the non-blocking case `suspend` is cascading upward the call stack to finally arrive at the highest coroutine level where the coroutine is finally taken off the thread, freeing it. What's still magic to me is how the function "at the end" (i.e. lowest nesting) is handled. E.g. think of `delay(1000)`: it removes the coroutine in a non-blocking way from the thread but somewhere must be a code who "counts down" and re-attaches the coroutine  from which `delay` was called (and therefore blocks its thread)?

Comment: Under the hood, you have message loops installed on all these threads. It's the same way Executors work, or thread pools in Rx, or the Handlers on Android. Each thread has a while loop that handles messages sent to it. Think of a message as a Runnable that has the next chunk of code the coroutine needs to run, up to its next point of suspension. The coroutines system under the hood submits a chunk of a coroutine to the appropriate thread's message handler. It will get run on the next iteration of the loop. Then it's free again to handle other messages.

Comment: There may be a single thread somewhere under the hood of a Dispatcher managing its `delay()` calls, but it's not like one thread per `delay()` call needs to be blocked. Timed future events get scheduled to be fired.  The actual implementation of the delay depends on which dispatcher is being used. For example, if you're using Dispatchers.Main and you're on Android, then it's using Android's Main Looper to handle and schedule messages. It's not consuming an additional thread to hook into that system and post a Runnable to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets assume a one threaded environment without asynchronous programming

Asynchronous programming can be achieved even on single threaded environment, example: `asyncio` in Python and `node.js`. How? Coroutines just take turns *(in micro/milliseconds*) on a single thread and give notion of concurrency, but they are not truly concurrent. This is still very useful for IO-bound tasks, because they trigger some work and wait for the result. For CPU-bound task, single thread is not enough/possible for concurrency.

> But if nothing suspends makeLongRunningNetworkCall() isn't the thread still blocked by makeLongRunningNetworkCall()? Or does suspend rather mean the whole coroutine is taken off the thread?

When coroutine is suspended, it is completely taken off the thread, and frees it. Later on when coroutine is resumed, it might resume on different thread.

> But then again, who assures the response of the network call is captured? I mean the "waiting" for the network result has to be done somewhere or else the result might be missed?

[No thread is required](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) to wait for the result, otherwise we would be just offloading works to dedicated Thread Pools of each library (network io, database, file io, ...) and create another layer of abstraction. Then there wouldn't be real benefit if each library has separate thread *(per read/write request)* that waits for the result.

**So how to await result without sitting on a thread?**

Simplified explanation is io-library calls *(directly/indirectly)* OS's low level functions, which calls device driver at some point. Device driver returns to OS immediately and request is now in flight and performed asynchronously.

> [Regardless of the type](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2201309&seqNum=3) of I/O request, **internally I/O operations** issued to a driver on behalf of the application are **performed asynchronously**; that is, once an I/O request has been initiated, the device driver returns to the I/O system. Whether or not the I/O system returns immediately to the caller depends on whether the handle was opened for synchronous or asynchronous I/O.

The OS returns to the library, which returns to the caller in some form *(callback/Future/Observable etc)* and caller is not blocked. **No thread is waiting** for the result.

> [Some time after](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) the request started, the device finishes handling request. It notifies the CPU via an interrupt... The device driver’s Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) responds to the interrupt... then Deferred Procedure Call (DPC) is queued... The DPC takes the IRP representing the initial request and marks it as “complete”. However, that “completion” status only exists at the OS level. OS queues a Asynchronous Procedure Call (APC) to the thread owning the device’s underlying HANDLE... Since Library/BCL has already registered the handle with the I/O Completion Port (IOCP), which is part of the thread pool. So an I/O thread pool thread is borrowed briefly to execute the APC, which notifies the task that it’s complete.

> There was no thread while the request was in flight. When the request completed, various threads were “borrowed” or had work briefly queued to them. This work is usually on the order of a millisecond or so (e.g., the APC running on the thread pool) down to a microsecond or so (e.g., the ISR). But there is no thread that was blocked, just waiting for that request to complete.